# VBA Problem - License Information for this component not found - How to identify which component?

Tags: vba, microstation

I have a VBA file that is working fine on 10 PC's. VBA is hosted within a drafting package called MicroStation / PowerDraft. On 2 more computers when setting up the files as normal i run into an error which says

> License information for this component not found. You do not have an appropriate license to use this functionality in the design environment

When checking through the VBA project i cant find any reference as to which file is causing the issue but also how to fix it? I have found a few articles on here and through Google which all direct to a Microsoft support page that is now a dead link. Can anyone help? All PC's are the same, Windows 10 64 Bit, same version of MicroStation, same Software and all Windows Updates up to date. The Files being referenced are below. They are all located and registered.

```
mscomctl.ocx
comdlg32.ocx
ieframe.dll
stdole2.tlb
msado27.tlb
```

Plus some more that i cant file the filename of.

Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
Adobe Acrobat Browser Control Type Library 1.0
Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine object Library
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Take a look: https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Troubleshooting/KB/KB00682

Comment: Do you actually have Access 2016 installed on the machine? That would be my first guess

Comment: @HarassedDad Isn't the item mentioned just the ADO library, not the MS Access object model library? Access wouldn't need to be present in order to use ADO, would it?

Comment: I'd wonder about `comdlg32.ocx` on a 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: The ADO library is called "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects " (and a version number). "Microsoft Access 16 Object Library" is indeed the access front end library and requires access to be installed :-(

Comment: Access is not installed, but the Access Database Engine is.
I havent had any issues with comdlg32.ocx previously. Plus with VBA i cant find an alternative that comes packaged with Windows? The client doesn't want any extra files to be installed. I would be happy to hear of alternatives that might help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7 days late so you should have resolved this **but if not** or in case others are looking

Many reasons that message is raised partly to do with UAC level at install time and the mixed ages of **MSoffice components**. The root problem is possibly a missing OFFICE registry value the cause is described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/license-information-for-this-component-not-found-you-don-t-have-an-appropriate-l

but for MicroStation you must during install be using the **correct "pre-requisites"** so check the related versions of product **and** requisite

some potential "fixes" are described here [Getting VB6 to reveal which component doesn't have a design time license installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144599/getting-vb6-to-reveal-which-component-doesnt-have-a-design-time-license-install) but links are old eg they should lead to say http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195353/en-us

1.Q194751 FILE: VB6Cli.exe Fixes License Problems with Visual Basic 6.0
2.Q195353 FILE: VBUSC.EXE Provides Licensing for Discontinued Controls

these have solved the issue for some users as described here  https://communities.bentley.com/products/building/building_analysis___design/f/aecosim-speedikon-forum/96029/install-aecosim

I found vbusc at [this link](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Troubleshooting/KB/KB00682) which running as admin on x64 gave a positive update message however as I'm no longer running a VB enhanced PowerDraft can't confirm it solves this issue.