# License information not found ... the MSDN collection does not exist?

Tags: vb6

I performed a new installation of VB6 / Visual Basic 6, but when I try to generate the executable this error is occurring:

> 'License information for this component not found...'

The application is compiling correctly.

Any suggestion?

[image: Error in Visual Basic 6]

Comment: The help system requires the installation of the last version of MSDN that supported VB6 which I think was October 2000. The License information error may be for a control which hasn't been registered properly. There used to be a MS program available to re-register all the controls but I'm not sure whether it's still available anywhere nowadays.

Comment: There could be a licensing issue with some third party dll/ocx component your VB project is referencing.

Comment: What controls are being referenced in the project?

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144599/getting-vb6-to-reveal-which-component-doesnt-have-a-design-time-license-install/60841098

Comment: @JohnEason there were two, one is still available. I wrote about this [in an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145844/15639) - I linked to two KB articles which each linked to a tool. The link for tool "one" is broken, but tool "two" still works I think.

Comment: @MarkJ I've just looked in my archives and found the exe that I downloaded from Microsoft years ago together with the associated readme file. It certainly isn't called VBUSC.exe though and the readmefile is somewhat different to the one in the article that links to so it may be for later versions of the controls. Mine is VBC6.exe and it has 3 DLL files with it which appear to hold the license codes.

Comment: Installing VB6 properly goes a long way toward avoiding this.  I hate to think what kind of mess your registry is now.  Both phases of installing VB6 and VS Tools should be run elevated, as well as the install of the MSDN Library docs.